# Wrapper for Phidgets not working

Tags: c++, c++11

I made a C++ wrapper for `phidgets` C library , I currently have `PhidgetDevice.h`  for a generic Phidget device,here is the header:

```
#ifndef PHIDGET_DEVICE_H
#define PHIDGET_DEVICE_H

#include <phidget21.h>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>


#define COMMON_IO_EVENT_CALLBACK(name) int CCONV name(CPhidgetHandle phid, void* userPtr)
#define ERROR_EVENT_CALLBACK(name) int CCONV name(CPhidgetHandle phid, void *userPtr, int errorCode, const char *errorString)

enum DeviceType
{
    DEVICE_NULL,
    DEVICE_KIT, 
    DEVICE_TEMPERATURE_SENSOR, 
    DEVICE_MOTION_SENSOR
};


class PhidgetDevice /* base class for every phidget device*/
{
public:
    PhidgetDevice() : m_type(DEVICE_NULL) {}
    explicit PhidgetDevice(DeviceType type) : m_type(type) {}
    void SetType(DeviceType type) { m_type = type; }

    virtual DeviceType GetType() { return m_type; }

    virtual void CCONV SetAttachHandler(CPhidgetHandle IFK, int(__stdcall * callback) (CPhidgetHandle phid, void *userPtr), void *userptr) { CPhidget_set_OnAttach_Handler(IFK, callback, userptr); }
    virtual void CCONV SetDetachHandler(CPhidgetHandle handle, int(__stdcall * callback) (CPhidgetHandle phid, void* userPtr), void * userptr) { CPhidget_set_OnDetach_Handler(handle, callback, userptr); }
    virtual void CCONV SetErrorHandler(CPhidgetHandle handle, int(__stdcall * callback) (CPhidgetHandle phid, void* userPtr, int errorCode, const char *errorString), void * userptr) { CPhidget_set_OnError_Handler(handle, callback, userptr); }
protected:
    DeviceType m_type;
};
#endif
```

This makes messy C Phidget functions look quite a bit better.
Now, this compiles fine on Visual Studio 2013 but when I try to compile it with g++ 4.8 including `-std=c++11` I get :

> PhidgetDevice.h:34:72: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token   virtual
>   void CCONV SetAttachHandler(CPhidgetHandle IFK, int(__stdcall *
>   callback) (CPhidgetHandle phid, void *userPtr), void *userptr) {
>   CPhidget_set_OnAttach_Handler(IFK, callback, userptr); }

And more of those, all complaining about function pointers though.

What's wrong with my function pointer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function pointer definitions are fine, it's the `__stdcall` keyword that is causing the issues with gcc. The `__stdcall` keyword defines the calling convention the compiler will use for the function it is specified for; specifically `__stdcall` itself (the double underscore then stdcall wording) is a MS specific keyword for calling conventions, if you wish to maintain this with gcc, you could do something like the following:

```
#ifndef WIN32
    #ifndef __stdcall
        #define __stdcall __attribute__((stdcall))
    #endif
#endif
```

Though you will probably find it will largely be ignored by the compiler (as a gcc warning: `warning: 'stdcall' attribute ignored`).